# dhtmlx tree - Setting ID of each element

Tags: tree, dhtmlx

After finally getting my tree to populate from a remote php file, the nodes in the tree lack any form of unique identification.

How do I set the id attribute in the tree so that I can do something meaningful with it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the ID is not visible in the HTML, but if I add this to my javascript, it pops up the id I assigned:

```
itemTree.attachEvent("onClick", function(id){
    alert(id);
});
```

So, it's been there the entire time.

http://docs.dhtmlx.com/api__dhtmlxtree_onclick_event.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set IDs in a tree structure: xml, json, etc...
If there is no id - tree will not work correctly